# How can I reuse @helper functions that are not in App_Code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some @helper functions, but the thing is I don't want to put them all in the App_Code to make them visible in the entire project.

Is there any other way to make them visible in the project?

---

I'm interested in doing this with @helper functions and not others  (partial views, static/extension methods) because I would:

- have them in a folder to my liking instead of App_Code and be globally accessible
- have template advantages (syntax highlighting, no string cocatenation etc.)
- not have to specify paths to reuse (as in partial views) - just short names, autocompleted

Answer (score 0):

You can write standard class methods and use them instead of helper functions. For example, you can create HtmlHelpers class:

```
 public static class HtmlHelpers
 {
    public static HtmlString Hello(string Name)
    {
       return new HtmlString("Hello <b>" + Name + "</b>!");
    }
 }
```

and then in your Razor view, you can call it like this:

```
<div>@HtmlHelpers.Hello("World")</div>
```

and it will produce HTML:

```
<div>Hello <b>World</b>!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's an alternative to consider, but I want to keep having the template advantages.

Comment: How about partial views?

Comment: Well, it's not the same thing, I have to specify the entire path every time I would reuse it whereas with the helper the name is shorter and I also get autcomplete.

Comment: All these requirements on what you are expecting should really be provided in the original question, otherwise it is hard to guess which solution would suite your needs.